# MediaRecorder does not record video only recording audio

Tags: android, audio, video

my Video Recorder app does not record video it only records the audio with the file extension of .mp4. There's no error returned in logcat. So, I can't figure it out whats wrong with my code.

Anyone knows this issue? Or any suggestions on what to use to record a video.

Here's my code:

```
public class VideoHolderCallback implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    MediaRecorder recorder;
    ...
    public void configureRecorder(){
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        recorder.setOutputFile(filePath);
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    }
    ...

}
```

Comment: you added permission 'android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO' in manifest like this right?

Comment: yeah, i have all the permission in manifest.

Comment: Hi, I tried my code in another device, it works. But not in Superpad III (China Tab) Model number: MOMO15 Android Version: 2.3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Video capture using the Android framework requires careful management of the Camera object and coordination with the MediaRecorder class"

"Unlike taking pictures with a device camera, capturing video requires a very particular call order. You must follow a specific order of execution to successfully prepare for and capture video with your application, as detailed below."

please look at the instructions and code snippets given here(also make sure you have ) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video

also make sure you have the required manifest declarations
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#manifest

Answer (score 2):

You should try it in the following order:

```
public class VideoHolderCallback implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
MediaRecorder recorder;
...
public void configureRecorder(){

    if(camera == null) {
        camera = Camera.open();
        camera.unlock();
    }
    recorder.setCamera(camera);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
    recorder.setOutputFile(filePath);
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
    recorder.prepare();
}
```

This piece of code should be working well for you. Feel free to change the AudioEncoder to something else than AAC, although it is the most efficient for low kbps.

Answer (score 0):

//try with your mic once

```
 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

[refer here:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html)